# C++ Tic tac toe program

Tags: c++

I am writing a tic-tac-toe program for a pretty basic C++ course and have a problem that's stumped me for a bit.

Below is the code for the `userMove()` function that takes input from the user and writes an '`X`' to the char array `board[2][2]`.  It works most of the time, but the problem is if the user inputs `row = 1 column = 0`, both `board[1][0]` and `board[0][2]` are changed to 'X'.

Does anyone see why this is happening?

```
//! The function userMove().
/*!
 The function userMove() takes two integer inputs from the terminal user,
 checks to see if the move is a valid one, and updates the char array board.
 */
void userMove() //take player's move
{
   //! The int row stores the user's first integer input.
   int row;
   //! The int column stores the user's second integer input.
   int column;

   cout << "Enter the row where you'd like your X:";
   cin >> row;
   cout << "Enter the column where you'd like your X:";
   cin >> column;

    //! This if statement checks that the user has selected a blank space for
    //! their next move.  If the space is already taken, the user is informed
    //! with an error message and the userMove() function is called
    //! recursively.
   if(board[row][column] == ' ')
   {
      board[row][column] = 'X';
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Invalid move\n";
      this->userMove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates/initializes `board`?

Comment: You need to make the board 3x3, not 2x2: `char board[3][3];`

Comment: ooga is correct - array dimensions are the number of entries in the array not the highest index to the array

Comment: The char array `board[2][2]` doesn't _have_ an element `board[0][2]`...

Comment: I see nothing wrong here. Could you post the part of the code that calls the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dimensions are wrong. Array dimensions count elements, instead of denoting the highest index:

```
char board[3][3];

/**
 * Now you may access the following:
 *
 *   board[0][0]
 *   board[0][1]
 *   board[0][2]
 *   board[1][0]
 *   board[1][1]
 *   board[1][2]
 *   board[2][0]
 *   board[2][1]
 *   board[2][2]
 */
```

With a `board[2][2]`, you have fewer elements than you think, and when you try to do things like getting the value of the non-existent element `board[0][2]`, you may *just so happen* to get the value of `board[1][0]` instead (due to how memory accesses work, and how arrays are laid out in memory) — that's why you think the write is occurring on both of these elements.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define your board as

```
char board[3][3];
```

for it to be 3x3. This allows indices from 0 to 2.

Also, you shouldn't really be calling the function recursively when a simple loop would do.